# MONGODB - adding a field in collection to a field in Item array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, collections, field

Suppose I have a document of the following prototype.

```
{
  cust_id: "abc123",
  ord_date: ISODate("2012-11-02T17:04:11.102Z"),
  status: 'A',
  price: 50,
  items: [
       { sku: "xxx", qty: 25, price: 1 },
       { sku: "yyy", qty: 25, price: 1 } 
  ]
}
```

My requirement is to get the total price for SKU "XXX" which is 50 * 25 (Price times quantity). How can I achieve this query's result in MONGODB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to achieve the solution to this by separating the query into two blocks as below.

var pipeline1 = [

{

{

"$unwind": "$items"

},

```
$match: {
    items.sku: "xxx"
},
$project: {
    "product":
```

{

$multiply: ["$items.qty","$items.price"]

},
        _id: 0
    }
}];

R = db.tb.aggregate( pipeline );

Answer (score 0):

```
db.YOUR_COLLECTION.aggregate({ 
    $match: {
        items.sku: "xxx"
    },
    $project: {
        "product": {$multiply: ["$items.qty","$items.price"]},
        _id: 0
    }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I already tried and this is the error i got. "$multiply only supports numeric or date types, not Array". Any other suggestions please?